# Typo in Br.SO's tour page

Tags: bug, status-pronto, markdown

I was poking around [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](http://Br.stackoverflow.com), and I went to their [tour page](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) (from the big banner at the top.) I would have posted this in their Meta, but given that I can't spell 'português' the same way twice, let along speak it, I decided to post in a more... comfortable venue.

Basically, I noticed this text:

> Nos níveis mais altos, você terá acesso às **ferramentas de moderação**especiais. Você poderá trabalhar ao lado de nossos moderadores da comunidade para manter o site focado e útil.

Notice the `**` there - it looks like it should be rendered as bold, but there isn't a space at the end of the terminating bold-markdown. Could we fix this?

Comment: Of course, I have no idea if this is a duplicate of something on m.br.so - can someone who can speak that other language (I don't want to try to spell it) search for it for me?

Comment: I know. If only Google had a translation service. Darn Portugeese.

Comment: I understand now that Br.so is not simply an automatic google translate of SO and vice versa. What a missed oppertunity.

Comment: Só está faltando um [meta-tag:status-aceito].

Comment: Esta e a outra questão em inglês estão sendo discutidas no Metão: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214277/foreign-language-questions-shouldnt-be-migrated/214282#214282

Answer (score 6):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.